# website generated e-mails are not reaching all users (php mailer)

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I am building a website for a group of kitchen chefs that allows new members to subscribe without any action from the owner.

When subscribing, new users should receive an e-mail with an activation link, in order to validate their address.

In the beginning I was using the function mail(), but a few addresses weren't receiving anything from the website, so I switched to php mailer.

php mailer code (no errors shown during execution, before I had echoes to check)

```
require_once ('layout/phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php');
$mail = new PHPMailer(true); 
try {
    $mail->AddReplyTo("$NoreplyMailURL","$NoreplyMailNAME");
                        $mail->AddAddress($mdest);
                        $mail->SetFrom("$NoreplyMailURL","$NoreplyMailNAME");
                        $mail->AddReplyTo("$NoreplyMailURL","$NoreplyMailNAME");
                        $mail->Subject = "$mobj";
                        $mail->AltBody = strip_tags ($mmex); // optional - MsgHTML will create an alternate automatically
                        $mail->MsgHTML($mmex);
                        $mail->Send();
}catch (phpmailerException $e) {
} catch (Exception $e) {
}
```

$NoreplyMailURL is the (existing) web site e-mail address

$NoreplyMailNAME is something like "Chef Enrico"

$mobj is a sentence like "new password for our website" or "account activation link"

$mmex is the message text formatted in html

Gmail, some hotmail and other users are receiving our e-mails,

some hotmail, bluewin.ch and libero.it are not.

Do you have any suggestions on how to make this code stronger? Is it possible that if receiving providers does not support HTML formatting, the e-mail is not shown? I guess they should see all tags if that was the case, am I wrong?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: if phpmailer returns true, then it's done. you need to check your mail server's logs to see what happened after phpmailer handed it over. e.g. phpmailer walks your envelope down to the street corner and drops it into the mailbox. if the mailbox then gets nuked by a drunk driver, that's not phpmailer's fault.

Comment: Are you seeing a common pattern or anything? Such as: 100% of the missing emails were sent to Yahoo addresses.

Comment: Ok, but how can I check? Some providers are like banks for their logs...

I was thinking that maybe I was missing some information for my function, like "knock three times fast and two times slow".

Comment: I still have very little data, for now it is:
50% failures on hotmail,
100% on libero and 100% on bluewin (but here we have 1 and 2 users)

Comment: This sounds more like a spam filtering thing to me. Have people checked their spam or they are simply not receiving anything at all?

Comment: With or without PHPMailer, you're sending via your local mail server, so any information about what is happening to your messages will be found in your mail server log.

Comment: Sounds like an issue with your DNS TXT records. Have you tried running your sender domain name through something like this TXT records tester: http://mxtoolbox.com/TXTLookup.aspx